# What does // mean in python?

Tags: python

What does // mean in python? When I was looking at scripts, I had seen it, but was unsure of its main function. Could someone please explain what it means?

The line with the code looked something like:

```
num = 5//x
```

Comment: See: integer division.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google [search](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html)

TLDF; it's floor division

Comment: Yeah when I searched google the answers seemed pretty complicated and I didn't really understand. Thanks for telling me a simple answer that it is floor division.